# How to zoom in programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm working on ability to zoom in by clicking on a button, just like I can with my mouse scroll. I tried setting `MinValue` and `MaxValue` for `X` axis, but when I do this, then zooming with mouse scroll gets broken and stops updating `MinValue` and `MaxValue`. How can I zoom in without breaking mouse scroll zoom?

```
private double? _minX;
public double? MinX {
    get => _minX;
    set => SetValue(ref _minX, value);
}

public void ZoomIn()
{
    if (MinX == null || MaxX == null)
        return;

    MaxX -= 1000;
    MinY = null;
    MaxY = null;
}
```

And my view:

```
<Button Content="+" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="2" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [ZoomIn()]"></Button>
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" Zoom="X" Pan="X">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis MinValue="{Binding MinX, FallbackValue=0}" MaxValue="{Binding MaxX, FallbackValue=100}" 
                  LabelFormatter="{Binding FormatterX}"></lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Comment: What's in your `_data`?

Comment: @J3soon A bunch of series, each with a list of `double`'s. I updated the question, because `_data` isn't really important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to set `Mode=TwoWay` for axis:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:Axis MinValue="{Binding MinX, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxValue="{Binding MaxX, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              LabelFormatter="{Binding FormatterX}"></lvc:Axis>
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```